# ActiveJDBC no models found , eclipse windows

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jdbc, activejdbc

I'm working with activejdbc in eclipse windows  and I did what is mentioned [here](http://javalite.io/eclipseIntegration) to configure eclipse to be able to run activejdbc, but I get this error every time I want to work with database, I think the problem is because of instrumentation, maybe eclipse does not work as what activejdbc needs or maybe I have done the eclipse configuration the wrong way (more info:  the instrumentation.sh file doesn't run with bash, but I can run "mvn process-classes" with cmd). Here's full stack trace:

```
you are trying to work with models, but no models are found. Maybe you
have no models in project, or you did not instrument the models. It is
expected that you have a file activejdbc_models.properties on
classpath Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.a2k.company.model.UserModel
--> [])] with root cause org.javalite.activejdbc.InitException
```

Also,  `activejdbc_models.properties` is created (maybe eclipse ignores the instrumentation ) 
I also got "execution not covered by lifecycle", so I added the plugin management(available in the mentioned link) in pom -> build tag.

thank's in advance.

Comment: try running on command-line and see if your project is working without Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your problem.
Please, see the animated attachment from my test.

[image]